# InverseTotient[ ]?

Tags: number-theory

Maple has a function `InverseTotient( c )`, which returns all those natural numbers $n$ whose Euler totient function $\phi( n ) = c$. Is there an equivalent
inverse of `EulerPhi[ ]` in Mathematica? If not, what would be a good method for
computing the inverse totient, faster than just trying all possibilities?

Comment: The hidden inverse totient function revealed by @MichaelE2 was a welcome surprise! (+1). For more information please see the CNT.m package in the Computational Number Theory  [book](https://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/books.html) by Bressoud and Wagon. Also see the [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/696/) by Maxim Rytin.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Reduce`EulerPhiInverse[6]
(*  {7, 9, 14, 18}  *)
```

Not sure why such things are hidden & undocumented, perhaps because it's available through `Reduce` and `Solve`:

```
Solve[EulerPhi[x] == 6, x, Integers]
(*
  {{x -> -18}, {x -> -14}, {x -> -9}, {x -> -7},
   {x -> 7}, {x -> 9}, {x -> 14}, {x -> 18}}
*)
```